# "error" : "null exception" in timeseries query on Druid

Tags: java, druid

I am using timeseries query on my indexed data, the snippets belows:

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": "statistic-test-v1",
  "granualarity": "hour",
  "descending": "true",
  "aggregations":[{"type": "longSum", "name": "output_imp", "fieldName": "impression"}],
  "intervals": ["2016-08-22T01/2016-08-22T02"]
}
```

I am ensure that it's exactively in intervals and aggreagations params. But when I use command line to query it:

```
curl -L -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST --data-binary @quickstart/ants-data/time-series-query-statistic-test-v1.json http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/?pretty
```

The result like this:

```
{
  "error" : "null exception"
}
```

Can anyone explain why it come to error and help me to fix it ? Thanks a billions.

Answer (score 0):

It just simple mistake of synctax
edit `"granualarity"` to `"granularity"`, it works well.